# Why do humans have sex for recreational purposes?

Tags: sexual-reproduction, sexuality

It never made sense to me why human beings crave sex other than for reproducing. It controls our society. It causes heartache, jealousy, anger, low self-esteem etc.  Sometimes humans will have sex over and over again even though they have no intention of producing a baby. I know it feels good but it doesn’t make sense to do something that risky unless you want a progeny. Why is this so?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is posed in relation to the author’s philosophical opinions, rather than as a biological problem such as comparison with animals that only copulate when the female is “on heat”.

Answer (score 3):

> "*I know it feels good but it doesn’t make sense to do something that risky unless you want a progeny*"

This right here is where you are tripping up. It's not about what one wants. It's about the continuation of the human race and not risky at all from that perspective. In that case, anything that increases those chances is a good thing.

Just like eating. How often do you think "*I better eat something so I don't die*" instead of "*I want to eat that thing because it tastes good*" or "*I want to eat to get rid of this unpleasant hungry feeling.*"

Comment: Yeah you make a good point…….